# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop bulma

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I use [Bulma framework](https://bulma.io/) with React in my application, i use `column is-multiline` Bulmas class :

```
<div className="column">
   <div className="columns is-multiline"> <--- error in this line
    {this.renderPerksAndBenefits(
      props.data.defaultPerksAndBenefits,
      props.data.translatedPerksAndBenefits
    )}
  </div>
</div>
```

and i've got the error:`Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` I use keys and set key values when it's possible in loops or etc but i don't know what can i use here in case i don't have any unique value to use like a key, i tried to use `key="columns"` and the similar values but it didn't work, I would like to know how can i solve it and is any default keys value exist ?
UDP renderPerksAndBenefits method:

```
renderPerksAndBenefits = (
    defaultPerksAndBenefits,
    translatedPerksAndBenefits
) => {
    return defaultPerksAndBenefits.nodes.map((node, index) => {
      const finalData = {
        ...node,
        ...translatedPerksAndBenefits[index],
      }
      return finalData.perksAndBenefits.map(({ icon, description, title }) => (
        <>
          <div className="column" key={icon.file.title}>
            <div className="columns is-multiline">
              <img
                className="perks-and-benefits__icon"
                src={icon.file.url}
                alt={icon.file.title}
              />
              <div className="perks-and-benefits__title">{title}</div>
              <div className="perks-and-benefits__description">
                {description}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      ))
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please include all code necessary to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. Can you update question with at least the function `renderPerksAndBenefits`?

Comment: @DrewReese sure i already updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react key needs to be on the outer-most element returned by the map function in order to be unique amongst its siblings. As written each key *is* unique amongst its siblings, but it's the only child of each returned fragment, the fragments don't have keys so they aren't unique. Either move it to the `Fragment` or remove the `Fragment` and return it all in the div. (*the `Fragment` isn't really serving a purpose anyway since there's only a single node in it*)

```
return finalData.perksAndBenefits.map(({ icon, description, title }) => (
  <Fragment key={icon.file.title}>
    <div className="column" >
      <div className="columns is-multiline">
        <img
          className="perks-and-benefits__icon"
          src={icon.file.url}
          alt={icon.file.title}
        />
        <div className="perks-and-benefits__title">{title}</div>
        <div className="perks-and-benefits__description">
          {description}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
))
```

or

```
return finalData.perksAndBenefits.map(({ icon, description, title }) => (
  <div className="column" key={icon.file.title}>
    <div className="columns is-multiline">
      <img
        className="perks-and-benefits__icon"
        src={icon.file.url}
        alt={icon.file.title}
      />
      <div className="perks-and-benefits__title">{title}</div>
      <div className="perks-and-benefits__description">
        {description}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
))
```